# PHP: Fetch content from a html page using xpath()

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to fetch the content of a div in a html page using xpath and domdocument. This is the structure of the page:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="div1"></div>
<span class="span1></span>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

I want to get only the content of p, not spans and divs. I came thru this xpath expression **.//*[@id='content']/p** but guess something's not right because i'm getting only the first p. Tried using other expression with following-sibling and node() but all return the first p only.

```
.//*[@id='content']/span/following-sibling::p
.//*[@id='content']/node()[self::p]
```

This is how's used xpath:

```
$domDocument=new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->encoding = 'UFT8';
$domDocument->loadHTML($page);
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$domNodeList = $domXPath->query($this->xpath);
$content = $this->GetHTMLFromDom($domNodeList);
```

And this is how i get html from nodes:

```
private function GetHTMLFromDom($domNodeList){
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$node = $domNodeList->item(0);   
 foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode)
 $domDocument->appendChild($domDocument->importNode($childNode, true));
return $domDocument->saveHTML();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
//div[@id='content']/p
```

Result in the wanted node set (five `p` elements)

**EDIT**: Now it's clear what is your problem. You need to iterate over the NodeList:

```
private function GetHTMLFromDom($domNodeList){ 
   $domDocument = new DOMDocument(); 
   foreach ($nodelist as $node) {
      $domDocument->appendChild($domDocument->importNode($node, true)); 
   }
   return $domDocument->saveHTML(); 
}
```

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks for the answer but //div[@id='content']/p
 dont works for me, i get only the firts p.

Comment: @Luciano: Then the problem lies somewhere else in your code. Try after query this: `echo $domNodeList->length`

Comment: @Alejandro: the number of nodes is right, but i still get the first p only. Could it be an error given by tidy() function. I get the content of the page with curl, but then i parse it with $tidy->parseString($curl_res);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
return $tidy;
Finally i send the this value as $page to domdocument.

Comment: @Alejandro: I've tried excluding tidy(), passing to domdocument the content i get with curl, but seems the same thing... is this the right way to use domdocument? (i've updated my question...)

Comment: @Luciano: Now with your remaining code it's clear what is your problem. Check my edit.

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks you so much, this was really helpful! I've been settled with the idea that there was an error with xpath... instead the solution is in a messed loop. Thanks again!

Comment: @Luciano: I'm glad it was helpfull. I'm not a PHP expert, but I think it would be better to get the document reference as `$domDocument = $domNodeList->item(0)->ownerDocument` and into the iteration block `$strResult += $domDocument->saveHTML($node)`, so then return the `$strResult`.